# How to remove N number of bytes from end of file, only if they match a specified array of bytes

Tags: c#, io

I am running into an issue building a program to process files provided. These files are XML files formatted with UTF-8. Oddly, some files end with `0x0A 0x00`, and cause our XML parser to throw an error. I am looking to build a function to remove these bytes on the end of a file if they exist, without "hard coding" `0x0A 0x00`. Ideally this function could be used in the future for any similar behavior with an array of any size.

Here is the exception:

```
System.Xml.XmlException:
hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 250, position 1.
```

This occurs in some files, but not all. The root cause of this behavior is yet to be discovered.

I'm sorry, I do not have a code sample, as I have not been able to get anything remotely close to work :) I will edit this post if I get something somewhat working.

Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: please show the code where you  are using your parser so we can see what parameters are passed in it

Comment: `0x0A` is line feed - that's usually fine, and most parsers know what to do with that; `0x00` is `NUL` - often used as a string terminator in C/C++, for example, so it sounds like an off-by-one error in some C/C++ code that is writing the file; however, I think in your case you can simply scan for the `NUL` (0) and trim the file *there*. In ASCII/UTF-8 text, you should never see a `NUL` (note for completeness: in UTF-16, depending on the endian-ness, `0x000A` or `0x0A00` is simply line-feed; this doesn't apply in *this* case, though)

Comment: side note: another common error when dealing with files is to *overwrite* one file in a binary way, **without** remembering to truncate it; if the new contents are longer, that's fine, but if the new contents are shorter, that can leave a lot of garbage at the end of a file. No idea if it applies here, but I've seen this **so many times** that it warrants a mention.

Comment: I agree it sounds like an error / oversight, I just confirmed the rest of the file is encoded with UTF-8, Here's a snippet of the code being used to read the file:
`XElement xElement = XElement.Load(filePath);'
This works great for all the files without this specific issue :)

Comment: That's odd, do you only ever see 0x0A or is there other data sometimes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick, keep in mind though this does not have any error handling built in, this is just the barebones functionality:

```
static void TrimFile(string filePath, byte[] badBytes)
    {
        using (FileStream file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[badBytes.Length];
            file.Seek(-badBytes.Length, SeekOrigin.End);
            file.Read(bytes, 0, badBytes.Length);

            if (Enumerable.SequenceEqual(bytes, badBytes))
            {
                file.SetLength(Math.Max(0, file.Length - badBytes.Length));
            }                
        }
    }
```

You can call it like this:

```
TrimFile(filePath, new byte[] { 0x0A, 0x00 });
```

Here's a test file I created with `0xCA 0xFE 0xFF 0xFF` at the end (some bunk data)

```
62 75 6E 6B 20 66 69 6C 65 CA FE FF FF 
bunk fileÊþÿÿ
```

After running `TrimFile(filePath, new byte[] { 0xCA, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xFF });`

```
62 75 6E 6B 20 66 69 6C 65
bunk file
```

Hope this comes in handy!

Comment: This might be exactly what I was looking for, thank you!